# Iterating through JSON to find if a defined object exists

Tags: python, arrays, json, find, loops

Thanks for helping out. I am working in python.

I'm requesting a json page, and loading it.

```
fooList = json.load(urllib.urlopen(
    "https://path.to.json.com/request?"))
```

It looks something like this:

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "foo": "2323582"
      },
      {
         "foo": "32689023"
      },
      {
         "foo": "125815512"
      },
      {
         "foo": "1252015"
      },
      {
         "foo": "12518505"
      },
      {
         "foo": "109251907590"
      },
      {
         "foo": "2158019258"
      },
      {
         "foo": "2198059018"
      }
   ]
}
```

I have a defined object

```
obj = 1252015
```

I then want to iterate through that list, and present a boolean answer as to whether or not `obj` exists in `fooList`

```
findObj = 'This is where I need help'
```

Intended result:

```
print findObj
True
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> print any(x['foo']=='1252015' for x in yourJson['data'])
True
```

`any` accepts any generator `g=<generator>` which returns boolean values, and is equivalent to `g[0] or g[1] or g[2] or ... or g[N]`. Of course if you didn't just want to search `yourJson['data']`, that would be a different story, and you'd want to define a recursive function.

Comment: Small but important detail: the value of `foo` is a *string*.